# Is Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm Problem NP-Hard or NP-Complete

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography, np-complete, discrete-logarithms

I have trouble classifying Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm Problem as NP-Hard or NP-Complete. Where does ECDLP belong? Any brief comprehensive answer is encouraged. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think anyone knows....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Why, please enlighten me?

Comment: It's unknown. You'll be famous if you can prove it to be NP hard or NP complete...

Comment: @Why is it unknown? Why is it not NP-Hard?

Comment: Because there is no proof that it is or is not. There are many open problems in this area. Cryptography is based on ignorance.

Comment: You first need a clean definition on how you define the input size. For a fixed curve, discrete logarithm is obviously O(1) as there are only a fixed number of candidates that need to be checked.